# Plot legend for multiple histograms plotted on top of each other ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, legend

I've made this multiple histogram plot in ggplot and now I want to add a legend for both the light purple part and the dark purple part. I know the conventional way is to to it with aes, but I can't seem to figure out how I integrate this feature as one into my multiple histogram plot.

I don't shy manual labour, but more sophisticated solutions are preferred. Anyone help me out?

```
#dataframe
set.seed(20)
df <- data.frame(expl = rbinom(n=100, size = 1, prob=0.08),
             resp = sample(50:100, size = 100, replace  = T))

#graph
graph <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = resp))

graph +
   geom_histogram(fill = "#BEBADA", alpha = 0.5, bins = 10) +
   geom_histogram(data = subset(df, expl == '1'), fill = "#BEBADA", bins = 10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is already in the long format that is well suited for `ggplot`; you just need to map `expl` to alpha. In general, if you find yourself making multiples of the same geom, you probably want to rethink either the shape of your data or your approach for feeding it into geoms.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(20)
df <- data.frame(expl = rbinom(n=100, size = 1, prob=0.08),
                 resp = sample(50:100, size = 100, replace  = T))
```

To map `expl` onto alpha, make it a factor, and then assign that to `alpha` inside your `aes`. Then you can set the alpha scale to values of 0.5 and 1.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = resp, alpha = as.factor(expl))) +
  geom_histogram(fill = "#bebada", bins = 10) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.5, 1))
```

[image]

However, differentiating by alpha is a little awkward. You could instead map to fill and use light and dark purples:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = resp, fill = as.factor(expl))) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 10) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("0" = "mediumpurple1", "1" = "mediumpurple4"))
```

[image]

Note also that you can adjust the position of the histogram bars if you need to, by assigning `geom_histogram(position = ...)`, where you could fill in with something such as `"dodge"` if that's what you'd like.

Comment: Thank you camille, for the elegant solution and explanation. I choose for an alpha to differentiate, because in a different graph I use the purple color #bebada to indicate a specific subpopulation. As to make the presentation easier to the reader, I want to use exactly the same color scheme, which is possible when differentiating with alpha

Comment: Just one more question though. With this script, I can't seem to adjust the legend title and labels. I am using scale_fill_discrete(name = "Legend", labels = c("Condition 1", "Condition 2") in addition to your script, but R just returns the original graph like you depict. Do you know of a workaround?

Comment: Never mind, I worked it out and edited your answer. I don't know how to change the image you send along

Answer (score -1):

If you want a legend on the alpha value, the idea is to include it as an aesthetic rather than as a direct argument as you tried. In order to do this, a simple solution is to enrich the data frame used by ggplot:

```
df2 <- rbind(
  cbind(df, filter="all lines"), 
  cbind(subset(df, expl == '1'), filter="expl==1") 
  )
```

`df2` corresponds to `df` after appending the lines from your subset of interest (with a field `filter` telling from which copy each record comes)

Then, this solves your problem

```
ggplot(df2, aes(resp, alpha=filter)) + 
  geom_histogram(fill="#BEBADA", bins=10, position="identity") +
  scale_alpha_discrete(range=c(.5,1))
```